# Why does my input placeholder text jump in IE?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, sass

first i will show you the peeks and explain the thing

chrome, all good:

http://puu.sh/rLTy1/e2a8a98e21.png - this is the unfocused input, displaying properly
http://puu.sh/rLTzA/2d38154c13.png - focused, still all good

exactly the same goes for mozilla, gg wp

introducing IE:

edge, as the page finished loading, unfocused
http://puu.sh/rLTCZ/a449447d4d.png - you can probably notice the thext is slightly shifted
http://puu.sh/rLTEU/c5160b5e8d.png - after i select it once, it jumps to its normal position and stays like that

this also goes for emulated 11 10 and 9 versions from the edge

but if i load it in the actual 11
http://puu.sh/rLTJR/e7c71c6749.png - unfocused, as the page finished loading
http://puu.sh/rLTLk/dab069b0ab.png - after i focus it it stays like this. close but no cigar IE

same goes for emulated 10 and 9 versions from the actual 11

why God, why does this happen?

```
<div class="header__search">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Keyword or model#">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go</button>
                </span>
            </div>
....
</div>
```

the HTML of the input

and the SASS of it

```
.header__search
  position: relative
  padding: 15px 25px

  background: #c9e1bc

  .input-group
    width: 31.5%

    input
      box-shadow: none
      height: 35px
      line-height: 35px
      font-size: 12px
      border-color: #538c53

    button
      max-height: 35px
      background-color: #6a9b6a
      border: 1px solid #538c53
      font-size: 12px
      padding: 8px 12px
      color: #FFFFFF
      border-radius: 0

    button:hover
      background-color: #5e945e
      border-color: #3b7c3b
      color: #FFFFFF

    input
      border-radius: 0

    button
      border-radius: 0

  iframe
    position: absolute
    top: 50%
    right: 68px
    margin-top: -9px



.header__search__input
  float: left

  height: 30px

  padding: 0 10px

  min-width: 200px

  border: none
  outline: none

  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px

.header__search__button
  padding: 5px 12px

  color: #FFFFFF
  font-weight: bold

  outline: none
  border: none

  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0

  background: #DEA72D


.header__search__button:hover
  background: #B98718
```

i also use bootstrap as some may have noticed. the 3.3.6 version

Comment: Please provide a working example (jsfiddle or so-snippet for example)

Comment: As above but also it is annoying when people post SASS, SCSS or Less rather than CSS when it is a frontend question as it makes it harder for people to recreate and therefore answer your question.